# If a child who is 7 years old and has not reached the age of puberty realizes that something is bad and unfair and still does so, is it written as sin

Tags: halal-haram, fiqh, hadith-interpretation, sin, muslim-practices

If a child who is 7 years old and has not reached the age of puberty realizes that something is bad and unfair and still does so, is it written as a sin and a bad act even though he is a child?

Answer (score 1):

He is a child a child doesn't know right and wrong ,he may understand it on the surface but doesn't realize it internally till puberty.He has to make mistakes so he can learn .Its important not to interfere in his learning and natural development.